# Construct BufferedReader with BufferedReader as reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Can I do this subj? I mean:

```
 BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file")));
 BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(reader1);
```

What will happen if I'll try to use BufferedReader (second one) in this case? Does it is correct?

Comment: Have you tried it? The answer is that it works and wastes time and space.

Comment: "Have you tried it" is not a great response. Trying it can only tell you that something works (or doesn't) in one specific setting. It doesn't tell you if it's always going to work or if it's bad design or if it works, but only by chance ...

Comment: I haven't try it. I want use same statement in my project. But I think it would be very slow.

Comment: It almost certainly wouldn't be "very slow". There might be a *very small* performance penalty, but the actual file I/O is almost definitely several magnitudes bigger than that overhead (even with the fastest SSDs available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct in the sense that it will work:

You can construct a `BufferedReader` from any valid `Reader`, even another `BufferedReader`.

It won't really improve performance or have any other beneficial effects, however. You should simply use `reader1` and not create the second one.

It can even have negative effects if you start *mixing* calls to `reader1` and `reader2`, but that's just the general idea of stream in Java: once you wrap a stream (or reader/writer), you should no longer access it directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I'll review design of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can decorate any `Reader` with a `BufferedReader`, but it doesn't give you any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It will use the below constructor to create the second BufferedReader. I would assume there would be a subtle performance loss because now you have two buffers with the same size.

```
 /**
  * Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses a default-sized
  * input buffer.
  *
  * @param  in   A Reader
  */
  public BufferedReader(Reader in) {
      this (in, defaultCharBufferSize);
  }
```

http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/BufferedReader-source.html